# Programmes won't open in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I decided to try Lubuntu to see what it was about. After setting everything up, I installed Libre Office, which works perfectly. I then attempted to install Spotify and Brackets. When I try to launch Spotify or Brackets, nothing happens, and after about one minute, I get the folllowing error:
[Error Message that I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzgW5.png)

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to resolve the issue. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

I looked forward to your problem and found two solutions.

1. Try reinstalling Spotify and Barckets.

   2.Reinstall your Ubuntu system with the command:
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

*Note that step 2 erases your data so back all your data before reinstalling.

Hope this works for you as this worked for my friend :D !!!

Comment: I have Windows along with Lubuntu. Will it be affected?

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure let me check and will tell you

Comment: Well it mostly won't but I heard theres a tiny bug that does that. Therefore, it might be a risk. According to my friend it worked perfect.

Comment: When I enter this command I get the following: Unknown option: a
Usage: dpkg-reconfigure [options] packages
  -u,  --unseen-only  Show only not yet seen questions.
       --default-priority Use default priority instead of low.
       --force   Force reconfiguration of broken packages.
       --no-reload  Do not reload templates. (Use with caution.)
  -f, --frontend  Specify debconf frontend to use.
  -p, --priority  Specify minimum priority question to show.
        --terse   Enable terse mode.

Comment: Try this-  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop